# Printout the method name of a derived class by calling method of a base class

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following class in c#, should be easy to follow through

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public void PrintMethodNames()
    {   // This line might needs change
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(BaseAbstract).GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseAbstract
{
    public void MethodA() { }
    public void MethodB() { }
    public void MethodC() { }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BaseAbstract ba = new DerivedClass();
        ba.PrintMethodNames();
        // desired printout 
        // MethodA
        // MethodB
        // MethodC
        // but obviously not working
    }
}
```

So what am I looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. `MethodA`, `MethodB`, and `MethodC` are methods, not properties, so you need to use [`GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) instead of [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx).
2. You should be using the current instance type ([`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx)) instead of the type of the base class (`typeof(BaseAbstract)`).
3. You need to constrain reflection using [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) in order to get just the methods defined on the derived class.  Otherwise, without these flags, you will get all methods defined on the type (like `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, and even `PrintMethodNames`).

This prints what you expect:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public void PrintMethodNames()
    {
        BindingFlags flags =
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Static;

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in GetType().GetMethods(flags))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that he want to list all DerivedCalss methods from BaseClass (opposite). Base class does not know it's Derived class and that is the problem.

Comment: @HABJAN: the code I provided does this. If you swap out his `BaseAbstract` with my version above and run the program, you will see that it prints the desired output (just the methods defined in `DerivedClass`).

Comment: @HABJAN: See point #2: `GetType` returns the runtime type of the instance, not the static type in which `GetType` is called. So, in this specific case, `GetType` returns `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `typeof(BaseAbstract).GetProperties()` with `this.GetType().GetProperties()`.

Comment: thx for the quick reply, but I am going to give the answer credit to Chris Schmich adding the BindingFlag code